Creating a Manifold for Images and Motion for Robot Navigation
I have a robot that moves randomly around an apartment using two wheels. Each wheel can be powered independently: applying the same power to both wheels makes the robot move forward, while applying the same power in reverse makes it move backward.
As the robot moves, it captures 32x32 RGB images of its surroundings. For each image, I also have a record of the action taken—the left and right wheel speeds—that led to that particular image.
What I’m aiming for is to create a representation of the apartment as a continuous, unified "landscape." In this landscape, each motion (described by the left and right wheel speeds) would lead to a specific point, represented by an image or some equivalent feature. This would allow the robot to navigate intentionally to a particular spot in the apartment by moving toward the corresponding point in the landscape.
I’ve gathered nearly 100,000 records of the robot’s movements and corresponding images, along with the image features extracted from them. Now, I want to use this data to help the robot navigate its environment in a purposeful, directed way, so it can reach a desired image or location.

Why did you choose those tags?

@JoséCarlosSantos manifolds are a way the brain uses to make representations of some aspects of the world (like head direction). So, it's natural that manifolds can represent a navigable space like an apartment. What do you think would be suitable tags to find a solution with?

I think what you are asking for is a map of the apartment showing the image the robot saw from each place it visited. For that you need the position of the robot for each picture. What you have is the velocity (speed and direction) at each instant. So you have to integrate the velocity to get the position. For that you will also need the time each picture was taken.

Yes, i'm sort of looking for a map. I have collected the position for each picture, but for the goal, I'd want to have the robot develop a map without the locations beforehand - so that it's able to create maps in new apartments.

With the speed and direction data you can reconstruct the robot's path and build the map.

One can build a map using feature detection techniques and a bundle adjustment. How would you approach it? I'm looking for fresh perspective.

Your last comment asks for more than this mathematics stackexchange can help with. I suggest you delete the question and ask elsewhere.
